# .Net Core looking for a lower version of referenced assembly

Tags: c#, .net-core, dll, assemblies

Hi have an external dll in my .net core project that references System.IO.Abstractions 17.2.3

However, when my project tries to load this dll it throws the following error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.IO.Abstractions, Version=17.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=96bf224d23c43e59'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

My projects project.assets.json has no reference to it and neither does the dll's project.assets.json I'm referencing (it's one of our own dlls).

I tried adding this to my csproj of my web app but no joy

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
</PropertyGroup>
```

What could be causing it to look for 17.0.0.0 instead of 17.2.3?

Comment: assembly versions and package versions are not the same thing; there's a good chance that the assembly version inside package 17.2.3 is: 17.0.0; edit: verified - indeed, nuget version 17.2.3 contains assembly version 17.0.0.0, so: it is looking for the correct version; have you checked that it is in the build output? (you can see this [here](https://nuget.info/packages/System.IO.Abstractions/17.2.3) - expand the dlls on the right, and select for example lib/net461/System.IO.Abstractions.dll and look at the metadata in the panel below)

Comment: have you tried making sure you have an explicit package ref? i.e. add `<PackageReference Include="System.IO.Abstractions" Version="17.2.3" />` to your project?

Comment: @MarcGravell in \bin\Debug\net6.0 the dll has file and product version 17.2.3.42299

Comment: @MarcGravell the external dll has <PackageReference Include="System.IO.Abstractions" Version="17.2.3" /> in the csproj. Do you mean my webproject needs it?

Comment: yes, the file in the package 17.2.3 has assembly version 17.0.0.0 and file version 17.2.3.42299 - they're all different numbers, but: that is the correct file

Comment: @MarcGravell thank you. You've put me on the right path. Without an explicit reference, doing a clean before rebuild was deleting the reference dlls

Answer (score 0):

In Nuget make sure to set each package to `[get] the latest` instead of `least version`. Some other package may be getting the version that is causing your main code to have this error.